# OpenOffice Calc:- import records from MySQL table

Tags: mysql, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

**Preamble to my question:-**

I have a stock-broker's desktop application, from which a csv file is continually being updated on the hard disk.

I am trying to append live stock quotes from the csv file to an OpenOffice Calc file (which is always kept open).
I wish to keep the file open because I will be having stock-charts in it.

A python program which, when run, would append the new data from csv file into a MySQL table.
No problem in that.

**My question is---**

How do I import data from MySQL table into OO Calc and thereon keep on refreshing it.
For Excel, I figured out how to do it.
In OO Calc, I configured MySQL connection through "Tools--Options--OO Base--Connections".
It opens a window & shows tables.
Can someone pl. tell me how to achieve data-import & refresh from MySQL to OO Calc?
(Copy & paste can't be a good solution).

Thanks in advance,

Vineet

*(Disclosure:- I had asked a similar question but involving python & xlrd/xlwt perspective on this forum.)*

Comment: Try this python module for [http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/.  ](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/) for loading data into OO Calc. Then use either [https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/VBA_Properties](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/VBA_Properties) or keyboard shortcut for reload for refreshing.